# Manage a DC remotely via powershell on a computer not joined to the domain

Tags: active-directory, powershell, remote-access

What should be done? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do this although I'm not 100% sure if you can specify a trusted host that is not a domain member for a DC.

From `about_remote_troubleshooting`

> When the local computer is not in a domain, the following procedure is required
>       for remoting.

```
1. Configure the computer for HTTPS transport or add the names of the
   remote computers to the TrustedHosts list on the local computer.
   For instructions, see "How to Add a Computer to the TrustedHosts
   List" below.

2. Verify that a password is set on the workgroup-based computer. If a
   password is not set or the password value is empty, you cannot run
   remote commands.
   To set password for your user account, use User Accounts in Control
   Panel. 

3. Use the Credential parameter in all remote commands.
   This is required even when you are submitting the credentials
   of the current user.
```

and

> To view the list of trusted hosts, use
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> get-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
>
> To add the names of particular computers to the list of trusted hosts,
> use the following command format:
>
> set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value <ComputerName>
> ```